# Underscores in my session id

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, session

I'm trying to preserve a session across an AJAX request.  Simply calling `session_start()` is not picking up the existing session, and instead is creating a new session id.  My solution was to pass the session id to the PHP through the AJAX call, but this resulted in the following error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in ...

I believe this is because the current session id contains underscore characters, but that session id is being fetched by a call to `session_id()`, so how can it contain bad characters?

Simple example of what I mean:

JavaScript on page (using jQuery)

```
var sessID = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";  //sessID contains underscore characters
$.get('/path/to/script.php',{sid:sessID}, function(data) {
    //do something
});
```

script.php

```
<?php
session_id($_GET['sid']);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['some_key'];
?>
```

So I'm currently thinking to parse the session id on the first page, and replace any bad characters within it before trying to use it, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do or if I need to look elsewhere for a solution.

Comment: If `session_start()` isn't preserving your session on an AJAX call, you have a problem somewhere else. Are you regenerating the session id somewhere?

Comment: It's possible.  The session is actually being set in a Drupal module, but the JS and  the PHP that the JS interacts with are not part of the Drupal site.

Comment: You really should investigate the cookie problem in more details instead of opening up a new channel for transmitting the session id. Start with something like firebug or fiddler to check the cookie header in the server's response.

Comment: @VolkerK - yup, turns out that Drupal does something to block access to the session data. Calling the Drupal bootstrap rather than session_start fixes everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that underscores were not part of my problem at all.  The issue was caused by Drupal's session handling, and so it was necessary to call Drupal's bootstrap rather than `session_start` in the AJAX call target.

```
//use Drupal bootstrap instead of session_start() to access session data set by Drupal
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
```

Credit for solution: http://www.csdesignco.com/content/using-drupal-data-functions-and-session-variables-external-php-script

Comment: Important (at least in Drupal 7): your script MUST live in the drupal root folder, or this wont work! I had my ajax.php inside /modules/mystuff/ajax.php with all paths adjusted, but it would just start a new session on each requests. Moved it /ajax.php and it worked as described.

Comment: That wasn't the case for me, but it's good you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get('/path/to/script.php',{sid:<?php echo session_id(); ?>}, function(data) {
    //do something
});
```

should be

```
$.get('/path/to/script.php',{sid:"<?php echo session_id(); ?>"}, function(data) {
    //do something
});
```